# Displaying logged in gmail on my site using Python

Tags: python, urllib2, cookielib

I'm trying to display mobile gmail on my website into a div using python, but the problem is that I can't bring the active logged in session like if I would open gmail in a new tab, only I can show the login screen of the mobile gmail. Is there a way to achive this using urllib2 and coookielib? Here is the code so far:

```
import webapp2
import jinja2
import os
import urllib2
import cookielib

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):

    cj = cookielib.CookieJar()

    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

    response = opener.open("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/x/1dpiqa8pfqv8z-/?f=1")

    template_values = {
        'content_gmail': unicode(response.read(), encoding='utf-8')
    }

    template = jinja_environment.get_template('templates/index.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

    app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        ('/', MainHandler)
    ], 
debug=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't scrape gmail, use the API: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/gmail/v1

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @remus Respectfully, I'm pretty sure I did exactly what you recommend. The essential part of the answer was to recommend use of the API instead of the approach the OP asked about. The link was provided as an additional convenience.

Comment: Yup, but to be suitable to stack overflow, you should include the bits from the documentation (like authentication) and elaborate on why one would use the API in place of scraping.

Comment: The relevant discussion about links in answers is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/254929). This answer is still *somewhat useful* if the link is removed entirely. You could definitely improve it, but I disagree with @remus that it needs to be deleted.

Comment: @AirThomas doesn't need to be deleted - it's actually the best possible answer. Just think it needs expanding.

Comment: @remus Your above comment is identical to the auto-generated review comment when selecting "Recommend Deletion" and I was reviewing in that queue so I assumed you had made such a recommendation. If not, then I'm disagreeing with someone else. :)

Comment: Ah, yeah, well, uh that was me. But I now agree it doesn't need deleting.